# Should member method be const if returning a pointer or reference

Tags: c++

I often come into dilemma as to whether I should make a member method const or not in cases where both options work just fine and produce exactly same result.

Consider the following two sample classes:

```
class A
{
public:
    /* Valid const correctness */
    int get() const { return x; };

private:
    int x = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    /* Questionable const correctness */
    int* get() const { return x; };

private:
    int* x = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    int* x = b.get();

    // This defeats the purpose of const keyword
    x = new int(1);
}
```

Class `A` is a good example of const correctness; however, class `B` is questionable: it's questionable whether the `get()` member function should be marked as const or not.

`const` is supposed to imply that sub-object won't be modified, resulting in a compile-time error if the function modifies its members.

In first example, the function does not modify it's member and nor can the caller modify it; however, in the second example, the caller can modify the pointer, which makes the const keyword questionable.

I strive to be const correct as much as possible, but in these cases I'm not sure, so my question is, What would be a good code design? To put the const keyword or not if returning a reference or pointer which the caller can modify?

Comment: The `const` after the parameter list is for the implicit `this` parameter and has nothing to do with the return value. If you're not changing anything inside the member function, just mark it as const.

Comment: Is member variable `x` not `this->x`?

Comment: I don't see how, in your second example, you are defeating the purpose of the `const` qualifier. The `main` has its own `x` pointer which is  not `const`, and neither is the **return value** of the `B::get()` method. You seem to be muddling up various uses of `const`.

Comment: @metablaster You're returning the pointer by value.

Comment: @metablaster I think you want the signature to be `const int* get() {return x;}` or even ``const int* get() const {return x;}``

Comment: @Jason This doesn't change the essence of the question

Comment: @metablaster It does. You have misunderstood the position of the const as you have not written anything about placing const before the return type. The 2 positions of the const are for specifying 2 completely different things.

Comment: The `const` correctness is the same in both examples. Both are equivalent versions of `T get() const { return x; }` (where `x` is a data member of type `T`). The only difference is the type of `T`.

Comment: This basically depends on the class design. The standard library does both: `std::unique_ptr<int> const p1 = std::make_unique<int>();`  would allow you to do `*p1.get() = 42;`, but `std::vector<int> const v1{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` wouldn't allow for `v1.at(0) = 42;`. (The second one uses a reference instead of a pointer though, but the effects are similar.) Note: `std::vector<int>` basically implements equivalents of 2 overloaded member functions `int const* get() const`  and `int* get()`.

Comment: @AdrianMole problem is that class member data which is private can be modified outside the class, therefore omitting the const would produce same effect.

Comment: @metablaster No. Your `main` in the second example doesn't do ***anything*** to the private member `x` variable. It is a different variable. Sure, you could modify what the internal `x` (and thus, the returned pointer copy) *points* to. Is that what you're trying to ask about?

Comment: If an object is required to be (logically) unchanged by a member function, mark that member function `const`  (bearing in mind that a `const` member function can still change `mutable` members).  If the function returns a (non-pointer) member by value, that's it.  If the function returns a pointer or reference, you also need to consider whether it is acceptable for code to subsequently change whatever is pointed/referred to (whether a member of the object or not), and  `const` qualify the return type accordingly.

Comment: @AdrianMole I have updated my question to fix this problem with returning a value

Comment: Your edit introduced a compiler error. `int*& get() const { return x; }` doesn't compile, since the member variable is considered a `int* const`...

Comment: @fabian That's Interesting, seems like this answers the question.

Comment: You could still do something like `int& get() const { return *x; }` though, i.e. the object the pointer points to is modifiable...

Comment: With the added reference return type, your use of a pointer in the second example is misleading. You could just add the reference type to the plain `int` example. It would be the same compiler error.

Comment: I've re-edited since comments are about the original question, thank you guys for comments (and downvotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks about "returning a pointer or reference" and `const`-correctness for the `get()` member function. But the cases are very different for **pointers** (which are returned by copy<sup>1</sup>) and **references**.

The issue of invalid `const`-correctness for a getter that returns by reference is an important one.

The following code has 'proper' `const`-correctness, whether we have `T` as either `int` or `int*`:

```cpp
using T = int;

class Foo {
public:
    T get() const { return x; }
private:
    T x = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    T x = f.get();
}
```

However, when returning a *reference* to a data member, that data member is considered `const` in any function also declared `const` that returns it (unless it is declared `mutable`), so the following will not compile:

```cpp
using T = int;

class Foo {
public:
    T& get() const { return x; }
private:
    T x = 0;
};
```

This will generate a compiler error along the following lines (this is from clang-cl):

> error : binding reference of type 'T' (aka 'int') to value of type
> 'const T' (aka 'const int') drops 'const' qualifier

In the latter case, we **must** also add the `const` qualifier to the return type:

```cpp
using T = int;

class Foo {
public:
    const T& get() const { return x; }
private:
    T x = 0;
};
```

Further, that returned `const` reference cannot then be assigned to a non-const reference, so the use of those `const` qualifiers will prevent a caller from being able to modify the private data member:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Foo f;
//  T& x = f.get(); // Illegal
    const T& x = f.get(); // OK
//  x = 42; // Illegal
}
```

(Note that you *can* also add the leading `const` qualifier in the very first snippet I've shown – but that is redundant because the `get()` expression will only ever be an rvalue and can't be directly modified, anyway.)

---

<sup>1</sup> There, I am talking about a data member that is *itself* a pointer (and returned by copy). However, in the case where a getter returns the address of a data member, the above discussion about reference types applies in a very similar way, and the following code would be 'equivalent' in terms of the required `const`-correctness:

```cpp
using T = int;

class Foo {
public:
    const T* get() const { return &x; } // MUST return a const T*
private:
    T x = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
//  T* x = f.get(); // Illegal
    const T* x = f.get(); // OK
//  *x = 42; // Illegal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make methods `const` whenever it's possible. In your case it's possible, because `const` method makes `const B* this`, therefore `int* const x`. You can't change `x` to point to another `int`, but can return `int*`.

```
int* const x = nullptr;
int* y = x; // legal

// Equivalent:
using T = int*;
T const x1 = nullptr; // const T x1 = nullptr;
T y1 = x1; // legal

// Even more simple equivalent:
const int x2 = 0;
int y2 = x2; // legal
```

Comment: const keyword on member method makes much more sense when referring to pointer itself rather than value pointed by pointer, that was my mistake which I overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR it depends.

For pointers, there are two separate notions of constness.

```
int const * x; // pointed-to int is const
Int * const x; // the pointer itself is const
```

Same thing is true about smart pointers, e.g. `const unique_ptr<int>` and `unique_ptr<const int>`.

One could in principle create a "deep const" smart pointer, where constness of the pointer itself implies constness of the pointed-to object, but such smart pointets are rarely useful. They are not found in the standard library.

Containers on the other hand normally have deep constness.

So you should ask yourself: is my class going to be more like a pointer or more like a container?

If it is more like a pointer, a single `get() const` returning a non-const pointer is OK.

If it is more like a container, then have two overloaded `get()`:

```
int * get();
int const * get() const;
```

The same reasoning about references is valid. There are no smart references, but there are reference wrappers which act more or less as pointers.